# Hexadecimal -> Binary Art

Tags: code-golf, string, binary, hexadecimal

*Take a list of 2-digit hexadecimal numbers as input, and output the binary value, replacing each 1 with an 'X', and each 0 with a space.*

**For example**

Input = `FF, 81, 47, 99`.

- `FF` = `11111111` in binary, so print `XXXXXXXX`
- `81` = `10000001` in binary, so print `X      X`
- `47` = `01000111` in binary, so print  `X   XXX`
- `99` = `10011001` in binary, so print `X  XX  X`

Full output:

```
XXXXXXXX
X      X
 X   XXX
X  XX  X
```

**Clarifications**

- The hexadecimal numbers will always be 2-digits.
- There can be any number of hexadecimal numbers.
- You can choose to input in whatever format you want (separated by a space, comma, newline, etc.)
- The character to output for a `1` is `X`, and for `0` it is a  . This will not change.
- The outputs must be padded to length 8

Also, [apparently I wasn't clear enough](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=modifieddesc#comment78489_25167): **the input is in Hexadecimal (Base 16) *not denary (Base 10)***

**This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins!**

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25167)

Comment: Do we have to output the joined list or can we return the mapped list?

Comment: Should the binary representations be left-padded with `0`s to the length  of the longest or always to length 8?

Comment: @Seggan - I don't fully understand your question, but the output must be in the same format as the example in the question. This is not a [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) challenge.

Comment: @Shaggy - they must be padded to length 8, even if the biggest number is not 8 bits long.

Comment: Please edit the question to clearly indicate the padding requirement (people are not supposed to read all comments), and maybe include a test case to address that

Comment: For future challenges, consider relaxing the input and output requirements (such as allowing input in decimal or allowing a the answerer to choose the 1 character, not necessarily X). I don't think those restrictions make the challenge more interestin

Comment: Is accepting a list of lists of integers from \$[0,15]\$ valid (i.e. a list of numbers in base sixteen) or should this be tagged [tag:String]?

Comment: ...and if only a string input may we choose our alphabet or should we stick to `0-9A-F`? If the latter may we expect input in lower-case instead?

Comment: Also, this is a minor point, but why are you using "denary" instead of "decimal" (especially since you're calling base 16 "hexadecimal")?

Comment: Related https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/179225/84624

Comment: @JonathanAllan - I've tagged it [string](/questions/tagged/string). The alphabet must be either `0-9A-F` or `0-9a-f`.

Comment: @97.100.97.109 - I thought they were interchangeable. Anyway, it doesn't really affect the message, which is that the inputs must be in base 16.

Comment: Suggested test input, straight from the introduction to custom characters in the VIC-20 Programmer's Reference Guide: `3C 42 A5 81 A5 99 42 3C`

Comment: @MarkReed - I think, since this is quite a simple challenge, the test case in the question is sufficient.

Comment: The restriction on only being able to use space for 0 and X for 1 is embarrassing. What if a language can't output spaces or Xs?

Comment: @Joao-3 then it can output the codepoints of a space and `X`. If it can't do that, I would start to doubt if it's really a programming language at all.

Comment: @TheThonnu If it can't output codepoints, then use whatever's available (e.g. A and B). Another available option is "use whatever reasonable output format you can use".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 58 bytes

```python
while 1:print(f"{int(input(),16):08b}".translate(" X"*99))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3rcozMnNSFQytCooy80o00pSqQVRmXkFpiYamjqGZppWBRVKtkl5JUWJecU5iSaqGkkKEkpalpaYmxASoQQvWublxGRhwWRhymZhzWVpCRAE)

Takes each hex code on a new line from input, prints to standard out. Terminates on error (is that allowed?)

---

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 67 bytes

```python
lambda n:"\n".join(f"{int(x,16):08b}".translate(" X"*99)for x in n)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3nXMSc5NSEhXyrJRi8pT0svIz8zTSlKoz80o0KnQMzTStDCySapX0SooS84pzEktSNZQUIpS0LC010_KLFCoUMvMU8jShRmkUFIG0pWlEK7m5KekoKBkYgEgLQxBpYg4iLS2VYjWh6hcsgNAA)

Takes input as a list of hex strings and returns a string with newlines separating lines.

Comment: You're going to have to add `'\n'.join` somewhere. The output must be in the format of the example in the question.

Comment: also this doesn't work correctly, you need `bin(int(x,16))[2:].zfill(8)`, not `bin(int(x,16)).zfill(8)[2:]`

Comment: You can save a few bytes with `f'{int(x,16):>08b}'` instead of `bin(int(x,16))[2:].zfill(8)`

Comment: The `>` isn't necessary since we already know all the strings are of length 8.

Answer (score 13):

## Excel (ms365), <s>74</s>, <s>72</s>, <s>59</s>, 58 bytes

-14 Byte thanks to @[jdt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41374/jdt)

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(HEX2BIN(+A1:A4,8),"0"," "),"1","X")
```

[image]

---

Original answer using `BYROW()` for 71 bytes:

```
=BYROW(A:A,LAMBDA(a,CONCAT(IF(-MID(HEX2BIN(a,8),ROW(1:8),1),"X"," "))))
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: I searched for alternatives for nested `SUBSTITUTE` functions and came upon [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71138491/how-can-i-replace-multiple-string-at-once-in-excel) which did not really help =). It looks like you can save 1 byte: `=BYROW(A:A,LAMBDA(a,CONCAT(IF(-MID(HEX2BIN(a,8),ROW(1:8),1),"X"," "))))`.

Comment: @jdt yeah I looked into that too but things get longer than the nested `IF()`. Good spot on the fact a negative integer will also trigger the `TRUE` parameter. Adjusted!

Comment: `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(HEX2BIN(0&A1:A4,8),"0"," "),"1","X")`

Comment: @jdt, you pulled of a way to make `HEX2BIN()` take an array. Sweet!

Comment: You can get this a bit shorter by expecting input as a vertical array beginning at A1 and using number literals instead of wrapping them in strings - 52 bytes: `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(HEX2BIN(+A1#,8),0," "),1,"X")`

Answer (score 10):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-p`, <s>40</s> 31 bytes

Takes input on stdin separated by newlines.

```ruby
$_=("%08b
"%$_.hex).tr"01"," X"
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpclm0km6BUuyCpaUlaboW-1XibTWUVA0skriUVFXi9TJSKzT1SoqUDAyVdJQUIpQgqqCKF6x2c-OyMOQyMeeytIQIAQA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-mR`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
nG" X" ù8
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW1S&code=bkciIFgiIPk4&input=WyJGRiIgIjgxIiAiNDciICI5OSJd)

```
nG" X" ù8    :Implicit map of input array
n            :Convert from base
 G           :16
  " X"       :To base " X"
        ù8   :Left pad with spaces to length 8
             :Implicit output joined with newlines
```

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 60 bytes

*-1 thanks to [@MatthewJensen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/87728/matthew-jensen)*

Expects a list of 2-character hexadecimal strings.

```javascript
a=>a.map(s=>(g=k=>k--?" X"['0x'+s>>k&1]+g(k):'')(8)).join`
`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcTRCoIwFADQ975C7kO7F9tICNJg681vCETwYjp0tomT6O8Xnocz85djv03rLn14D2nUibVh9eEVozZotdPGSfmE7AWNuP5EHo1x56LNLTp6CEFYEqk5TL47dakPPoZlUEuwOGIDdQ2XDMri@HY/ripoidIf)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>             // a[] = input array
a.map(s =>       // for each string s in a[]:
  ( g = k =>     //   g is recursive function taking a counter k
    k-- ?        //   if k is not equal to 0 (decrement it afterwards):
      " X"[      //     append either ' ' or 'X':
        '0x' + s //       parse s as a hexadecimal string
        >> k     //       right-shift it by k position
        & 1      //       and isolate the least significant bit
      ]          //     end of lookup
      + g(k)     //     append the result of a recursive call
    :            //   else:
      ''         //     stop the recursion
  )(8)           //   initial call to g with k = 8
).join`\n`       // end of map(); join with line-feeds
```

Comment: Save one byte by starting recursion at 8: `a=>a.map(s=>(g=k=>k--?' X'['0x'+s>>k&1]+g(k):'')(8)).join\`
\``

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>61</s> 57 bytes

```
.
   $&
 (?=..[89A-F]|.[4-7C-F]|[2367ABEF])
X
+T`dA-F` Xo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fj0tBQUFFjUtBw95WTy/awtJR1y22Ri/aRNfcGcSKNjI2M3d0cnWL1eSK4NIOSUgBKkhQiMj//9/NjcvCkMvEnMvSEgA) Explanation:

```
.
   $&
```

Precede each digit with three spaces.

```
 (?=..[89A-F]|.[4-7C-F]|[2367ABEF])
X
```

Replace the spaces with `X`s where appropriate.

```
+T`dA-F` Xo
```

Reduce the remaining digit modulo 2 and replace with space or `X` as appropriate.

Comment: @JvdV From the OP: The hexadecimal numbers will always be 2-digits.

Comment: Had to re-read and you are absolutely correct!

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), `-p` 30 bytes

```perl
$_=sprintf"%08b
",hex;y/01/ X/
```

Pretty much identical to [Jordan's Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252383/108444)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3ra4oCgzryRNSdXAIolLSScjtcK6Ut/AUF8hQv//fzc3LgtDLhNzLkvLf/kFJZn5ecX/dQsA)

Comment: 24 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lYjPSc/Sb06RkEnola9wkIzOiO1Ivb/fzc3LgtDLhNzLkvLf/kFJZn5ecX/dQtyAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 5):

## [sed 4.2.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), `-E` <s>[178](https://tio.run/##VYzNDoIwEITvfYoeCCmguxZRYG/@wDOYWHsgGuNFTNoTxle3LiQc3GSTb2dmx92uITgEpLhtjof9rq7K7aZY53qFd0HCISlIQJ0tXVKjEySjTc6WZ2sUUfLBKeCKiWSGMQ/@I@FkRgyCOiarIEuMJuSVY8JKBemsnFD4bn6jYbThvSg/EUqu80MIbSsqLYpS1PW3f/lH/3Rh2fwA)</s> 141 bytes

```
s/./&FEDCBA9876543210:/g
s/(\w)\w*\1//g
s/\w/ /g
s/ +/&&&&/
s/ +/&&&&/
s/://
:
s/^(.+)\1:/\1: /
s/^ (.*)\1:/\1:X/
t
s/://
:z
s/^.{,7}$/ &/
tz
```

Takes newline-separated input

-35 thanks to [DLosc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)

#### Explanation

```
s/./&FEDCBA9876543210:/g  add hex digits to each input char
s/(\w)\w*\1//g            find index of input char in hex string
s/\w/ /g                  left is 2 strings which lengths corresponds to the input
s/ +/&&&&/
s/ +/&&&&/                multiply first strings' length by 16
s/://                     add the 2 strings, left is a unary number
:
s/^(.+)\1:/\1: /          convert to base 2, one bit at a time
s/^ (.*)\1:/\1:X/
t
s/://
:z
s/^.{,7}$/ &/             pad with spaces until length > 7
tz
```

Comment: Nice work! I did some rearranging and got it down to [143 bytes](https://tio.run/##K05N@f@/WF9PX83N1cXZydHSwtzM1MTYyNDASj@dq1hfI6ZcM6ZcK8ZQH8yNKddXADMUtPXVgEAflWmlr89llQRkxGnoaWvGGFrpA7ECSCZOQUNPCyYSoc9VkgRTXgWS1avWMa9V0VcAmlJS9f@/mxuXhSGXiTmXpeW//IKSzPy84v@6rgA).

Comment: Even the naïve approach is only [175 bytes](https://tio.run/##Ncy5DYAwDIXh3lOwADJHOFJyJDNkABCiAaQwP8bGwdWnX0@O60IUscCMDzeIWArDx4oZtNZCrQY5am2EWltm2nZCrT2G/68Vah2YaTsKtU4Y/r@zUKtjpq0XciXyHvoSTAfWPud17@cRKXcv "sed 4.2.2 – Try It Online").

Answer (score 5):

## [Brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 442 bytes

```
++++++++++>>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++[<<+>+>-]<----------------------------<++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>,[------------------------------------------------[-[-[-[-[-[-[-[-[-[--------[-[-[-[-[-[<<<.>>>[-]>]<[<....>>]>]<[<...>.>]>]<[<..>.<.>>]>]<[<..>..>]>]<[<.>.<..>>]>]<[<.>.<.>.>]>]<[<.>..<.>>]>]<[<.>...>]>]<[.<...>>]>]<[.<..>.>]>]<[.<.>.<.>>]>]<[.<.>..>]>]<[..<..>>]>]<[..<.>.>]>]<[...<.>>]>]<[....>],]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70yqSgxMy-tNDl7wYKlpSVpuha3GHdpw4GdnZ02BSDaxkbbTttON9ZGFw-wwWeEnZ1OND7N2EA0FogpZWNjowf0X7RurF2sTbSNHhDY2cHZdnpwtp2eDZKMnR5cBiSBkAErQ5JD1mWnB9OlZ4OwB6wdIY5kD5gHk0GyRQ_JDj0kG8COj9WJhUQhNCYXrHZzU7AwVDAxV7C0hAgBAA)

The input can be separated by every character with a value bigger than 'F'.

```
The working section looks like this:
| '\n' | 'X' | ' ' | {input character} | 0 (used for stopping loops) |

prepare the initial state
++++++++++ newline

prepare space and X
>>> ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ [<<+>+>-]
< ---------------------------- space
< ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ X

Go to start position and read char
>>,
[
  subtract '0'
  ------------------------------------------------
  [ if !0
    -[ if !1
      -[ if !2
        -[ if !3
          -[ if !4
            -[ if !5
              -[ if !6
                -[ if !7
                  -[ if !8
                    -[ if !9
                      subtract difference between 'A' and '9' 
                      -------
                      -[ if !A
                        -[ if !B
                          -[ if !C
                            -[ if !D
                              -[ if !E
                                -[ if !F
                                  print newline
                                  <<<.>>>
                                  clear input character
                                  [-]>
                                ]
                                <[ print 'F' <....>> ]>
                              ]
                              <[ print 'E' <...>.> ]>
                            ]
                            <[ print 'D' <..>.<.>> ]>
                          ]
                          <[ print 'C' <..>..> ]>
                        ]
                        <[ print 'B' <.>.<..>> ]>
                      ]
                      <[ print 'A' <.>.<.>.> ]>
                    ]
                    <[ print '9' <.>..<.>> ]>
                  ]
                  <[ print '8' <.>...> ]>
                ]
                <[ print '7' .<...>> ]>
              ]
              <[ print '6' .<..>.> ]>
            ]
            <[ print '5' .<.>.<.>> ]>
          ]
          <[ print '4' .<.>..> ]>
        ]
        <[ print '3' ..<..>> ]>
      ]
      <[ print '2' ..<.>.> ]>
    ]
    <[ print '1' ...<.>> ]>
  ]
  <[ print '0' ....> ]
  read next input
  ,
]
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>10</s> 8 bytes

```
H‛ Xτ8↳⁋
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJI4oCbIFjPhDjihrPigYsiLCIiLCJbXCJGRlwiLFwiODFcIixcIjQ3XCIsXCI5OVwiXSJd)

-2 thanks to Steffan

Port of Japt.

Comment: Your 6-byter suffers from the same issue with left-padding that my 5-byter did.

Comment: @Shaggy oops, fixed.

Answer (score 4):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>80</s> 74 bytes

```c
i;f(**b){for(i=8;*b;)putchar(i--?strtol(*b,0,16)&1<<i?88:32:(b++,i=8)+2);}
```

-3 bytes thanks to Arnauld!!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYvRCoMgGEbve4qfLoaaQrWxWRbd9RJjFyqzCa1GOXYRvfqc7rs48ME5mulRToP3VhhEiMKbmRdkWy6IEvj1dvohw2esW93i5hERRXNanPGhaBrbcV4fyxqpLKOhwVmJxe6f0k4IbwmExZyAu6/ueoMWNkj7PqWQ8iLydImsqkDIYRf/xKCoY5Hs/qvNKIfVs88P)

#### Alternative method proposed by Arnauld:

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 73 bytes

```c
i;f(**b){while(*b)putchar(++i%9?strtol(*b,0,16)&1<<8-i%9?88:32:!++b+10);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzNDoIwEITvPMVKomkpJFSMForxxksYD6Xhp0lFAzUcGl7d2jqHL5uZ2ZGZ1GIanFO8R0nSYruOSnfIX@@PkaOYESFqX94WM5uX9n6ap/SMD7SuWRYCxqriWO0IaQnNMd/cU6gJYRuBVxhIwHSLuT/gChbipolTiBkNPF0Cy9ITctj4/6VHoY55tLmv7LUYFpetPw)

This will only work correctly for the first 477,218,588 lines.

Comment: [77 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYtBDoIwFET3nOKHhWkLTagaLXwIOy5hXLTEYhMEAzUuCB7dSp3Fy0wyr@Vtr4bOe4uGMKbpYsaJINOok4SGbiuJH4v0@XLtXW2b83p2kxt7wnSapeJEd6IsbS1lcdgXIqO4@oeyA6FLBFuCxcDdZne5QgULxE0TpxBLEXg8B@b5Rshgxb9iSLhTjFb/bU2vutnz9w8) by doing one more iteration for the linefeed.

Comment: [73 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYzNDoIwEITvPMVKomkpJFSMForxxksYD6Xhp0lFAzUcGl7d2jqHL5uZ2ZGZ1GIanFO8R0nSYruOSnfIX@@PkaOYESFqX94WM5uX9n6ap/SMD7SuWRYCxqriWO0IaQnNMd/cU6gJYRuBVxhIwHSLuT/gChbipolTiBkNPF0Cy9ITctj4/6VHoY55tLmv7LUYFpetPw) but not 100% valid (it's not infinitely reusable because `i` will eventually overflow and not be congruent to 0 modulo 9 anymore when the function terminates).

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>[34](https://tio.run/##AUIAvf9odXNr//9tyK/DtuKGkV84K1I4JyBtISJYICLhuItCMTZt4oKs4bmB4oCmQzIiMTlBRiJ3////RkYgODEgNDcgOTk)</s> <s>[31](https://tio.run/##AT0Awv9odXNr//9tyK/DtnRtISJYICLhuIsrMjU2QjE2beKCrOG5geKApkMyIjE5QUYid////0ZGIDgxIDQ3IDk5)</s> 28 bytes

```
mȯötm!"X "ḋ+256B16m€f□…"1F"w
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AToAxf9odXNr//9tyK/DtnRtISJYICLhuIsrMjU2QjE2beKCrGbilqHigKYiMUYid////0ZGIDgxIDQ3IDk5)

Takes input as a space-separated argument
Husk is missing some useful functions such as pad and hex which makes this answer so long, or maybe I'm just bad.
-3 [DLosc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)
-3 [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)

#### Explanation

```
mȯötm!"X "ḋ+256B16m€f□…"1F"w
                           w  split on spaces
mȯö                           map the following ultra composed penta-function
                  m€f□…"1F"   map input to indices the generated string "1-9A-F"
               B16            convert from digits in base 16
           +256               add 256 to make the binary string 9 chars long      
          ḋ                   convert to digits in base 2
    m!"X "                    index into "X ", one-indexed modular
   t                          chop of first bit
                              implicit output joined on newlines
```

Comment: -1: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P1ejJFdRKUJB6eGObm0jUzMnQ7PcR01r0h5NW/ioYZmSoaWjm5Jm@f///93cFCwMFUzMFSwtAQ "Husk – Try It Online")

Comment: [26 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P1ejJFdRKUJB6eGObidDMyvD3EdNa9IeTVv4qGGZkqGbkmb5////3dwULAwVTMwVLC0B) by prepending a ```1``` digit instead of adding 256...

Comment: ...which would be [23 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P1ejJFdRKUJB6eGObidDMyvD3EdNa9IeTVv4qGGZkqHb////o5Xc3JR0lCwMgYSJOZCwtFSKBQA) by taking input as a list (as in the challenge description), rather than as a single string...

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/), 89 bytes

```python
lambda n:[print(bin(int(i,16))[2:].zfill(8).replace("1","X").replace("0"," "))for i in n]
```

Function which takes in a list of hexadecimal strings.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcyxCsIwEIDhVzluykEJRkXbgmufQagdUm3w4LyGGAd9@Rg3px@@4Y/vfF91V8LpUsQ/5psH7ceYWLOZWc2v3LgD0bjtJ/sJLGJasmmJ4q@LQYcNnvEPNhUAicKagIEVdCqhfuIrG7LPKFxLZRigdbA/Qtd9AQ)

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/), 98 bytes

```python
[print(*('X'if int(b)else' 'for b in bin(int(a,16))[2:].zfill(8)),sep='')for a in input().split()]
```

Takes input itself, no header/footer code.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYpBCoMwEEWvMruZERGsYrXQrWcoiAsDCR0IcTDpol4@mtX7vP/0n7576HJe9JCQqCL8oDgo27D10SKg2w8wtwIjgcqz1e3AvDxea3M68Z5G5jpafSNyibcSS9BfIm6ierm55jzPMLbQP2GaLg)

Comment: `a=lambda n:[print(bin(i)[2:].replace("1","X").replace("0"," "))for i in n]`.Works, but prints a list whose items are all None in the end.

Comment: @py3programmer - thanks. I think `bin(int(i,16))` was needed instead of just `bin(i)` since `bin` needs an integer as the parameter. Also, you need the `.zfill(8)` otherwise it won't print a leading space.

Comment: Late comment, just pointing out on my answer: If you allow input to be taken as `0xFF` instead of `FF`, you can shave off a byte by changing the `bin(i,16)` to `bin(i,0)`

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 60 bytes

```factor
[ [ hex> "%08b"sprintf "10""X "zip substitute print ] each ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcnBCoJAFAXQvV9xGWgbCkFa0NJo0yaCQFyMwzMHbUbnPTGKvn2KVmdxWm3Eh3i9nM7HHVofHlrEujt@dutRB6YAzewNw3r0FBwNYJpmcoYY04J9kkzLG2WJPMNmi6LAJ1ao0NHzALVK80bxGKyTFipLlbpBvewInhsWK7MQ/osapE2HOho9DPEL)

- `[ ... ] each` Call `[ ... ]` on each hex string in the input sequence
- `hex>` convert from hex to decimal
- `"%08b"sprintf` format as a binary number string left-padded with spaces 8 wide
- `"10""X "zip` create the following associative mapping: `{ { 49 88 } { 48 32 } }`
- `substitute` substitute characters in the binary string according to the mapping
- `print` print to stdout with a newline

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 10 bytes

```
1ZA8&B88*c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3zDK0ULNycJCK/n//2p1Nzd1HQV1C0MQaWIOIi0t1WsB)

#### How it works

```
      % Implicit input: cell array of char vectors.
1ZA   % Convert each char vector to number. Gives a numeric vector
8&B   % Convert each number to 8-digit binary. Gives an 8-column binary matrix
88*   % Multiply each element by 88 (ASCII code of 'X')
c     % Convert to char
      % Implicit display. char(0) is displayed as space
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 13 bytes

```
ＷＳ⟦◧⍘⍘↧ι¹⁶ X⁸
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iOSOxKDk_MWfBgqWlJWm6FjejyjMyc1IVNDzzCkpLgkuKMvPSNTQ1FQKAjBKN6IDEFJ_UtBINp8TiVKgkEtMnvzy1KBnI18jU1FEwNAMSSgoRSkDKQjNW03pJcVJyMdSe5dFKumU5SrFr3Ny4LAy5TMy5LC25IFIA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＷＳ              Loop over all lines of input
  ⟦             Output each result on its own line
       ι        Current line
      ↧         Lowercased
     ⍘  ¹⁶      Converted from base `16`
    ⍘      X    Converted to custom base ` X`
   ◧        ⁸   Left padded to length `8`
```

Answer (score 3):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 29 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
⍉' X'⌷⍨∘⊂2⊥⍣¯1(16⊥(⎕D,⎕A)∘⍳)¨
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=e9Q31dP/UdsEAwA&c=e9Tbqa4Qof6oZ/uj3hWPOmY86moyetS19FHv4kPrDTUMzYBsjUd9U110gISjJkhB72bNQysA&f=S1NQd3NTV1C3MAQSJuZAwtJSHQA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=f)

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 45 bytes

```
{"\n"/|'8$|'" X"@+2\16/+"0123456789ABCDEF"?x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6pWislT0q9Rt1CpUVdSiFBy0DaKMTTT11YyMDQyNjE1M7ewdHRydnF1U7KvqOXiSjCwSlPQUHJzU7JWsjAEEibmQMLSUkkTAKftENM=)

This is way too long...

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + coreutils + dc, <s>68</s> <s>58</s> 51 bytes

Takes input as arguments.

-10 bytes thanks to [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
-7 bytes thanks to [manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork)

```bash
for a;{
printf "%08s
" `dc<<<2o16i$a?n`|tr 01 \ X
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Py2/SCHRupqroCgzryRNQUnVwKKYS0khISXZxsbGKN/QLFMl0T4voaakSMHAUCFGIYKr9v///25u/y0M/5uY/7e0BAA)

Comment: [58 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Py2/SCHRupqroCgzryRNQUnVwKKYS0khISnZxsYmPymxONXWKMZaJdqgQiUxNqGmpEjBwFAhRiGCq/b///9ubv8tDP@bmP@3tAQA "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: @Steffan Very clever. Thanks!

Comment: Usually `dc` is shorter than `bc`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Py2/SCHRupqroCgzryRNQUnVwKKYS0khISXZxsbGKF8l2qBCJTE2L6GmpEjBwFAhRiGCq/b///9ubv8tDP@bmP@3tAQA "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: If you let `dc` do the conversion from base 16, you can save another character: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Py2/SCHRupqroCgzryRNQUnVwKKYS0khISXZxsbGKN/QLFMl0T4voaakSMHAUCFGIYKr9v///25u/y0M/5uY/7e0BAA "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: @manatwork Thanks! Looks like I need to dig into dc.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-l`, 17 bytes

```lisp
" X"@S*TDgFB16+E8
```

Takes the hex pairs as command-line arguments. [Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJcIiBYXCJAUypURGdGQjE2K0U4IiwiIiwiIiwiLWwgRkYgODEgNDcgOTkiXQ==)

#### Explanation

```lisp
" X"@S*TDgFB16+E8
         g         ;; List of command-line arguments
          FB16     ;; Converted (each) from base 16
              +    ;; Add (to each):
               E8  ;; 2 to the 8th power (256)
       TD          ;; Convert (each) to binary as a list of digits
     S*            ;; Get all but the first element of each
" X"@              ;; Use those 0's and 1's to index into this string
```

The result is a depth-2 nested list of spaces and X's. The `-l` flag concatenates each sublist together and outputs it on a separate line. (For a flagless version, add `P*` to the beginning of the code and `u` to the end.)

Answer (score 2):

## [simply](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/simply), 88 bytes

It's a long mess, but *works*!
(I've used `\n` for style, but an actual newline works as well, and that is reflected in the size of the answer.)

```
fn($L){$T=" X\n"&array_map($L,fn($V)each$x in run&format("%'08s2"&cb($V,16,2))out$T[$x])}
```

Creates an anonymous function that **outputs** the result.

This works by left-padding all binary values to 8 characters, then ends with "2".
For each character of the binary string, it outputs the *n* character in the string `" X\n"`.
For 0 outputs `" "`, for 1 outputs `"X"` and for 2 outputs `"\n"`.

### Example

```
$fn=fn($L){$T=" X\n"&array_map($L,fn($V)each$x in run&format("%'08s2"&cb($V,16,2))out$T[$x])};

run $F(["FF", "81", "47", "99"]);
```

Should output the expected result.

### Slightly more readable

Both versions do exactly the same.

```
fn($list) => {
    &array_map(
        $list, fn($line) => {
            $translation = " X\n";
            $temp = call &format("%'08s2", &convert_base($line, 16, 2));
            each $char in $temp {
                echo $translation[$char];
            }
        }
    );
}
```

For some reason, JavaScript doesn't like the original order, when I untangle the code.

Answer (score 2):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 75 bytes

```
;=fB;=n 4W+=n-nT1O I%/-aI>60a 48 55^2n 2'X\'' \'W=pP;=aAp;Cf;=aA GpT1;CfO''
```

[Try it online!](https://knight-lang.netlify.app/#WyI7PWZCOz1uIDRXKz1uLW5UMU8gSSUvLWFJPjYwYSA0OCA1NV4ybiAyJ1hcXCcnIFxcJ1c9cFA7PWFBcDtDZjs9YUEgR3BUMTtDZk8nJyIsIkZGXG44MVxuNDdcbjk5Il0=)

Input each hexidecimal value on a separate line.

Could be a bit shorter if it isn't required to output X's and spaces:

#### [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 72 bytes

```
;=fB;=n 4W+=n-nT1O++''%/-aI>60a 48 55^2n 2'\'W=pP;=aAp;Cf;=aA GpT1;CfO''
```

[Try it online!](https://knight-lang.netlify.app/#WyI7PWZCOz1uIDRXKz1uLW5UMU8rKycnJS8tYUk+NjBhIDQ4IDU1XjJuIDInXFwnVz1wUDs9YUFwO0NmOz1hQSBHcFQxO0NmTycnIiwiRkZcbjgxXG40N1xuOTkiXQ==)

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 63 bytes

```powershell
%{[convert]::ToString("0x1$_",2)}|% S*g 1|% *ce 1 X|% *ce 0 ' '
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmv7uamrqOgbmEIIk3MQaSlpbpCzX/V6ujk/Lyy1KKSWCurkPzgkqLMvHQNJYMKQ5V4JR0jzdoaVYVgrXQFQyCtlZyqYKgQAWUZKKgrqP//DwA)

Input comes from the pipeline.
Pretty straightforward; converts to binary, replaces 0 and 1.

```powershell
%{[convert]::ToString("0x1$_",2)}|% S*g 1|% *ce 1 X|% *ce 0 ' '
%{                              }                               # % is an alias for ForEach-Object, which processes the scriptblock {...} for each string coming in from the pipeline.
  [convert]::ToString("0x1$_",2)                                # converts the hexadecimal string in $_ to binary, with a leading 1 to avoid padding (saves one byte)
                                 |% S*g 1                       # pipe the binary string to ForEach-Object again, and call the MemberName method Substring(1), stripping off the leading "1"
                                         |% *ce 1 X|% *ce 0 ' ' # Pass the binary string through two more calls of the MemberName Replace(); output is implicit.
```

Answer (score 2):

## C# 10 (.NET 6) and later, 184 bytes

Doesn't work in TIO as it doesn't support .NET 6.

```cs
foreach(var i in Console.ReadLine().Split(',')){var a=Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(i,16),2).Replace("1","X").Replace("0"," ");a=new string(' ',8-a.Length)+a;Console.WriteLine(a);}
```

Asks for the hex numbers as input when started.

Output:

```cs
FF,81,47,99
XXXXXXXX
X      X
 X   XXX
X  XX  X
```

Ungolfed version:

```cs
var input = Console.ReadLine();                           // Ask for input
foreach (var i in input.Split(',')) {                     // Split with a comma, and for each part:
    var hex = Convert.ToInt32(i, 16);                     // Convert it to an integer
    var bin = Convert.ToString(hex, 2);                   // Convert it to it's binary representation
    var art = bin.Replace("1", "X").Replace("0", " ");    // Replace 1 with X, 0 with a space
    var padding = new string(' ', 8 - art.Length);        // Repeat a space as much as needed for padding
    art = padding + art;                                  // Append the padding to the start of the art string
    Console.WriteLine(art);                               // Write the final result
}
```

### Function version (155 bytes)

Thanks to [Seggan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/107299/seggan) for the suggestion.

```cs
void art(int[] n){foreach(var i in n){var a=Convert.ToString(i,2).Replace("1","X").Replace("0"," ");a=new string(' ',8-a.Length)+a;Console.WriteLine(a);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU5NSwMxED3v/oohlya4XVoRbAk9FXqqIFZQEA9DnG4HtokkcVWW/PY1aS9eHsN78z5MmBvnaZq@AtsODr8h0lnXpscQ4NG7zuMZxroKESMbGBx/wAOylSH6bHh7B/RdUOWluojoo2Qbs2DVeMzRaE5yQA8MbAtXbtxsnR3Ix/bZHS5Bkptb1T7RZ4@GpFiKRryKf8QiEyCUxo2lb7iWyxnMmtUc2z3ZLp7UDeocG1xP7YvnSHu2JFHplPK4sqtYr9tGWPzsdk3G1bLg3X3B9RqS0nWV6jRNfw)

Usage and output:

```cs
art(new int[] { 0xFF, 0x81, 0x47, 0x99 });
/* gives this output:
XXXXXXXX
X      X
 X   XXX
X  XX  X*/
```

Comment: I'm sure this could be shortened by making this a function and taking in a list of numbers

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: [104 bytes](https://tio.run/##RU5NS8NAFDw3v2LYg@xiIikItm5TD0JPCoIHhdrDEjfxQbsL@7ZVCfntcRMtvsMc5utNzUXtgx2OTK7F8zdHe9BZvTfMeAq@DeaALptxNJFqnDy949GQkxxDCmx3MKFlhW6YpEaSi9udy/0x4teCoLpQCaGb9MbUH/JkAhjk4FSXuDEBqhaaimJdahUuK8kX89WK1Lq8E6/iVkDoxIo3J3TfD/i7c71lVEj92VlopLOfmIagQ/m12eQJF/MRr29GXC7R5xg3prT6T957x35vr14CRftAzspJn02GPuuHHw)

Comment: note that you can do `our var res` in the function call - not that it affects anything here

Comment: [115](https://tio.run/##TY3BasMwEETP9lcsogcJHJOEQhN8DPhWKE2hgSQHocrugr0qWtVtEfp2V/Epl3d4w8wYXhnn7fzNSD0c/zjYsSnNoJnhxbve6xFiWXDQAQ1MDj/gWSNJDj4XzlfQvmcFcV6iTiKF85VU7PKoNp9y0h4QkIDUwRG7wdbvHoOVDyJmMVkf6jd3XNYkVltVv9qvQRsrxUZU4iTuxDoLEKrapQsJ1aS5KDpJ9geWU4iw/m3bKnO3ufHx6cb9HpJqyiKVaf4H) if you still want to use `Replace`

Comment: wait, is this even valid? question says you're supposed to take hexadecimal numbers (i.e. strings) as input

Comment: [148](https://tio.run/##TczBisIwFIXhdfsUlyCYQCxTlZmKS0FwIYgdUFAXIZN2LtREcmNhKH32ThBBt9/h/Jom2nkz3AltDeUfBXNdprpRRLDzrvbqCl2aUFABNbQOf2Cr0HIKPh5OF1C@JgHd8Jiqp4MVXRWzSv/yVnlAQAs2K28NBj6WYyFWzpJrTHbwGAwfsS5Ca3zIvl35SPAXbGyYTTnK/FPIqcj25tYobTjLmWRH9gYfEYAJWfRny8SyH5Kk4my9lkUu519ysYiYJn3aD/8)...?

Comment: @ASCII-only, that is true, you can also one on these [138](https://tio.run/##TY7LasMwEEXX9lcMQxcSOKZJSx54GQh0UShNoIUmC6HIjsAZFY3qUoS@3VEDfWxmce49l9E80c6b8YMtdbD94mDOTal7xQxP3nVenSGWBQcVrIbB2SM8KkuCg8/C2wGU71hCHK9R@8tJxjbvKn0Sg/JgwRKQXDti15v6xdtgxA3GDAbjQ71z26so/sADhbuZsNV0LquZrJ/Ne6@0ETjFCl/xH7jNAFBWy7QnlE0ai6IVZD7h55eIm03uLL/N@0U@qxUm2ZRFKtN4AQ) or ...

Comment: [128](https://tio.run/##PU5NS8NAED0nv2KYg@xiUhoVbd2mHoSCB0GooKAelriJC@0uzGwjsuS3x8XYzuHBvA/ea7hsPJnxwNZ1sP3hYPYqb3aaGZ7Id6T3EPOMgw62gd7bT3jU1gkOlAJvH6CpYwlx/JPaE@8K8IcA0wskI9WIqk1VuvkSvSZgsA6cjIkT1gWw9ULZslzPlaTzWtx71xsKs2f/4MLlheCiupZn1Wpl5Xp@h694i4AqOfHdoRqGMTt2GYYaUlmWw/@1wplvOE6LuNlggYsqwdVNguUSh2luykp1iqUJ7Hdm9kI2GDFp2ZAP4y8)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 26 bytes

```
' X'{~(8#2)#:[:".'16b'&,&>
```

Tacit function that expects a list of boxes using `[0-9a-f]`.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxS10hQr26TsNC2UhT2SraCqjc0CxJXU1HzQ6iYJMmV2pyRr5CmoKRQq2egmOQexhEYke0Ulqako6CkoUhiDQxB5GWlkqxCyDyAA)

```
' X'{~(8#2)#:[:".'16b'&,&>
                 '16b'&,&>  : prepend '16b' to each input cell and unbox
               ".           : Do, eval the list of strings
             [:             : Cap, makes do and the prepend eval as f(g(x))
      (8#2)#:               : convert to binary and pad to length 8
' X'{~                      : use result to index into ' X'
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Hb8j»T„X ‡
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fI8ki69DukEcN8yIUHjUs/P8/WsnNTUlHycIQSJiYAwlLS6VYAA)

Or alternatively:

```
H„ XÅвJ8j»
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f41HDPIWIw60XNnlZZB3a/f9/tJKbm5KOkoUhkDAxBxKWlkqxAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
H          # Convert the values in the (implicit) input-list from hexadecimal to integers
 b         # Then convert those base-10 integers to binary
  8j       # Pad leading spaces so all become length 8
    »      # Join the list with newline delimiter
         ‡ # Transliterate all
     T     # 10
      „X   # to "X ", replacing all 1s with "X" and 0s with " "
           # (after which the result is output implicitly)

H          # Convert the values in the (implicit) input-list from hexadecimal to integers
 „ XÅв     # Convert each integer to custom base-" X", which basically means to
           # base-length (2 in this case) and then indexing into the string
      J    # Join the inner character-lists to strings
       8j» # Same as above
           # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 99 bytes

```rust
|a|a.map(|s|format!("{:>8b}",u8::from_str_radix(&s,16).unwrap()).replace('0'," ").replace('1',"X"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9Ra4MwEMff/RTnPawJOJkwNps6Hwt9HgxhlJBpMgRNuiSug9rP7nQrUtz@cBz3u/tzd7ZzflAaWlFrQuEUNNKDYqA0cb5i7FOWjO20Nzsvbfbsba3fcwq3OXB4GnrRi7gVB9K7XhnbCh8SPLE8fTtj1KWMKWta7rzlVlT1F7lxUfJA404f7WiiNLby0IhSktXdKkLAK5CMoEBKh00gnJPWc/kRkgAuUmS8LHzF7RZjb7g5alkRGgGmyQLcPy7Aen0N9nE9fsfr8b3poNI0jSw9Y9mLLDOe55Nl3vqzc64mYXERRgv@m/9wmBr/zxdT4Iz3dBOch28)

Can be assigned a variable of type `fn(std::vec::IntoIter<String>)->_`

Answer (score 1):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) `-E`, <s>131</s> 121 bytes

*-10B thanks to [@Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)*

```
s/./X&/g
s/X([0-7])/ \1/g
y/89ABCDEF/01234567/
s/[4-7]/X&/g
s/[0-3]/ &/g
s/[2367]/X&/g
s/[0145]/ &/g
y/01234567/ X X X X/
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ODVlWbSSrqtS7IKlpSVpuhY3K4v19fQj1PTTuYr1IzSiDXTNYzX1FWIMgQKV-haWjk7OLq5u-gaGRsYmpmbm-kBV0SZANTAtQA3GsfoKUI6RsRmylKGJKVSuEmGCQgQE6kMcAHXHgtVublwWhlwm5lyWlhAhAA)

Comment: [121 bytes](https://tio.run/##K05N@f@/WF9PP0JNP52rWD9CI9pA1zxWU18hxhAoUKlvYeno5Ozi6qZvYGhkbGJqZq4PVBVtAlQD0wLUYByrrwDlGBmbIUsZmphC5SoRJihEQKD@//9ublwWhlwm5lyWlv/yC0oy8/OK/@u6AgA "sed 4.2.2 – Try It Online").

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), <s>10</s> 9.5 bytes (19 nibbles)

```
>>.``@hex:1@=$"X "
```

```
>>.``@hex:1@=$"X "
                     # implicit map over lines of input:
         :1@         # prepend with 1
      hex            # get the hexadecimal value
   ``@               # convert to binary digits
  .                  # and use each of these
            =$       # to index into
              "X "   # letters of the string "X ";
>>                   # finally, remove the first element
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [Windows Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd), 145 bytes

Length calculated by using Unix/LF as EOL, without an EOL at the end of the last line.

```
:s
@if %1.==. exit/b
@set/an=0x%1&set b=
:w
@set/ar=n%%2&set/an/=2
@set b=%r%%b%
@set b=%b:0=.%&if %b:~7,1%.==. goto w
@echo.%b:1=X%&shift&goto s
```

Input as command line parameters.

#### Ungolfed

The `@` suppresses the output of the command currently processed that would otherwise be echoed; "@echo off\n" would use 10 bytes, so suppressing lines individually is cheaper.

```
:s                      &REM Start label
@if %1.==. exit/b       &REM Leave if no more parameter from the command line
@set /a n=0x%1          &REM set n to the value of the first parameter (%1) as hexadecimal ("set /a" is an arithmetic operation)
@(set b=)               &REM Clear b (the output string)
:w                      &REM Start of the loop to calculate the binary representation of n
@set /a r=n%%2          &REM Set r to the remainder of n/2; % is the modulo operator, which must be doubled inside a batch script
@set /a n/=2            &REM Divide n by 2
@set b=%r%%b%           &REM Add the remainder to the output string
@set b=%b:0= %          &REM Replace every 0 in the output string with a space
@if %b:~7,1%.==. goto w &REM If the eight character in the output string is not set yet, continue with the conversion
@echo.%b:1=X%           &REM Replace every 1 in the output string with an X, and write the string
@shift                  &REM Shift the command line parameters to the left (former %2 is now %1, etc.)
@goto s                 &REM Lather, rinse, repeat
```

```
D:\cmd>.\CGSE_252379.cmd FF 81 47 99
XXXXXXXX
X      X
 X   XXX
X  XX  X
```

Answer (score 1):

## sh + coreutils, <s>82</s> 72 bytes

```bash
xxd -r -p|xxd -b|sed -E "s/^.{10}(.{53}).*/\1/g;s/ *$//g"|tr 01\  \ X\\n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcbNCkBAFAbQV/mS8lPmmhCy5hksbspfrJCxUMazD9lYndO1ajZjP69wqgqZRJwiz/E/c6DNeQ4IdgSb/tZpNb6UsBQ14pLh7YoriW5P@MSSpkIRfJtosvSxI5QMMGrmxZgH)

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 82 bytes

```
func[b][forall b[parse s: enbase/base b/1 2[8[change"1""X"| change"0"sp]]print s]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcdLCoMwEADQfU8xjAfQFMHPATxAV4VhFolObEFiyLQr9ewpgW4evCRLfshCfPNj9t8wk2Pye7LbBo6iTSqgI0hwVqUugKsN3Kmn@WXDKmgQn3jCfw1qZI7pHT6gzNkDVcc0XVAdvSm2XXEYLs4/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thon](https://github.com/nayakrujul/thon) `-el`, 16 bytes

```
C{16D" X"b8" "JO
```

**Explanation:**

```
C{16D" X"b8" "JO
C{                // Get a list of strings as input, and loop through the list
  16D             // Convert from base 16 to base 10
     " X"b        // Convert from base 10 to base " X"
          8" "J   // Fill with " " up to 8 characters
               O  // Output
```

(`-el` flag is needed to prevent the last line being output twice)

Comment: Several years ago, we dropped the rule that languages have to precede the challenge. So this is competing. Relevant meta post: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12877/lets-allow-newer-languages-versions-for-older-challenges

Comment: @Steffan thanks. I didn't know about that.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/nickbclifford/Ohm), 11 bytes

```
ôb€τ‥X r8Ü,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr///CWpEdNa863PGpYGqFQZHF4js7//9FKbm5KOgpKFoYg0sQcRFpaKsUCAA)

A neat little answer, in my opinion.

### Explained

```
ôb€τ‥X r8Ü,
ôb          # Convert each hex number to decimal then to binary
  €         # To each now-binary number:
   τ‥X r    #    Replace all 0s with spaces and 1s with Xs
        8Ü  #    Right-pad with spaces until the string is length 8
          , #    Print with a newline
```

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 83 bytes

```
2:?!^i:0(?;" "\ao
-:07@@af+)?$~-\
:?!v:2%@2,:1%->
00.>~$~1-
oa4.>~}}}}rl?!v" X"{?$~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38jKXjEu08pAw95aSUEpJjGfS9fKwNzBITFNW9NepU43hguooMzKSNXBSMfKUFXXjsvAQM@uTqXOUJcrP9EEyKwFgqIcoCIlhQilaqCe///d3CwMTcwtLQE)

**Explanation**

1. Subtract 32 from input. If the result is larger than 25, subtract 7.
   This gives us the decimal value of the input+16.
2. Repeat mod by 2, divide by 2 / mod by 1 to get the binary digits.
   Drop the first digit of the binary value.
   Since we added 16 to input this gives us the leading zeroes.
3. Do steps 1 and 2 one more time for the 2nd hex digit.
4. Reorder values, replace with "X" or " " and print each.
5. When done, print a newline and go back to 1.

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://raku-lang.org), 67 bytes (62 characters)

```
' X'.comb[words».parse-base(16)».fmt('%08b')».comb]».join».say
```

Expects one picture per line, hex values space-separated on each line. Written to operate on standard input; change `words` to `.words` to operate on the topic instead at the cost of another byte.

[Try it online!](https://glot.io/snippets/ggaxyc3uhc)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s><sup>[11](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/259766/1)</sup></s> 8 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
╨÷◘Jè∞╩:
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=d0f6084a8aecca3a&i=%5B%22FF%22,+%2281%22,+%2247%22,+%2299%22%5D)

Unpacks to:

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 10 bytes

```
m|H. X:B8)
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=m%7CH.+X%3AB8%29&i=%5B%22FF%22,+%2281%22,+%2247%22,+%2299%22%5D)

```
m          # map the following over the input array:
 |H        # convert from hex to decimal
      :B   # and then to base
   . X     # " X"
        8) # and pad to length 8
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 140 bytes

Golfed vesrion. [Attempt this online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZU_NSsQwEL73KYaANIEauijarVTQhYUFPS2KICJjm9SsbVLSKCyyb-AbeOlF32nfxnSzHsQ5fB_z9803n999iQ0eDdtb1XbGOtjlXBm-dNVCcyuwulJaRH_aq-qFz0zTiNIpo2dGvwnrhO35YxSZp5UvwzUqDe_R16uTh9n2oxISJMV86azSNdtzEYhLY1t0lBykWUWShXaiFpZ3aHvhE_pbcOZSabTrsEX_zWEyOWE-eIsdLYtzJT0WcRqzGGIQTS8gvovZ3lMHMLpqvVGKtu5zuLAW1_dB_YHlcKOVg8J_AT52TUrmc5IASdMRs8mIx6cjTqck3JVsfEdg-Uw7L-Qazc68wCbahLvDEPgH)

```scala
def f(a:String):String=String.format("%08d",Integer.parseInt(Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(a,16)))).map(c=>if(c=='0')' ' else 'X')
```

Ungolfed version. [Attempt this online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZVFRS8MwEMbX_oqjIE1ghg5Ft0kFHQwG-iSCICJZm87MNinX22DIfokve9Ff5JO_xrTppiKBy-XL3Xd337191Kks5PF2-76k_GjwdfCpy8oiQYsLbcUtZVMjUMnsWhsV_PleZC9ibItCpaStGVuzUkgKa_EUBHa2cDDcSG3gNQDIVA4506Za0ghuCbWZ850DSRsCsJKFC0x16e4EpobUXKGoJNbKPXx2D_qnfB8900biGpIWgI5P5BZLSSw8jAdZ2PtPtAPIXrX5Po11pTn_4SeUpi4kqcw15IuJUlYsheQCdA6Nk0AURxwid1RRK4juI0-AipZofnGcO3jTiVE6ZZjEeT2CS0S5fvBNPDpV7oymvSbtJwsnEzdIGMeNHfQbe3LW2OEw5G1HOW_GVjJ9ZpUjosJwX24T-OV2O97t-hs)

```scala
import scala.io.StdIn.readLine
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

object Main {
  def f(input: String): String = {
    val decimal = Integer.parseInt(input, 16)
    val binary =
      String.format("%08d", Integer.parseInt(Integer.toBinaryString(decimal)))
    val translated = binary.map(c => if (c == '0') ' ' else 'X')
    return translated;
  }
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    Array("FF", "00", "81", "47", "99").map(f).foreach(println);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `N`, 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
H` XBð8ṙ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPUglNjAlMjBYQiVDMyVCMDglRTElQjklOTkmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0lMjJGRiUyMiUyQyUyMCUyMjgxJTIyJTJDJTIwJTIyNDclMjIlMkMlMjAlMjI5OSUyMiZmbGFncz1OZQ==)

##### Explanation

```python
H` XBð8ṙ  # Implicit input
H         # From hexadecimal
 ` XB     # To base " X"
     ð8ṙ  # Pad to length 8
          # Implicit output
```