# Number to String in aaaaa way!

Tags: code-golf, string

In this challenge, you are going to take a number and turn it into a string, but not in the common way. You will use the `aaaaa` way!

The `aaaaa` way is simply replacing each digit of the input number with the letter at that position in the alphabet. For example, `11111` would become `aaaaa` and `21223` would become `babbc`. If the number is less than 5 digits you need to left-pad it with an "A". For example, `12` would be `AAAab`.

### Rules

- Your code can be a function or a complete program that outputs to STDOUT.
- The returned string must be 5 letters.
- It's obvious that the input would be a 1 to 5 digits number that has digits from 1 to 9.
- You can get both input and output in number and strings or in array form like [1,2,1,3,1] and ['a','b','a','c','a'].

---

### Test cases

```
In: 43213 -> Out: dcbac
In: 8645  -> Out: Ahfde
In: 342   -> Out: AAcdb
In: 99991 -> Out: iiiia
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so smallest program wins!

Comment: The rule states that input has digits `1` thru `9`. What about `0`? Does it become `j`?

Comment: @roblogic, no input wont have a 0. Only 1 to 9 and output is a to i.

Answer (score 14):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 44 bytes

```python
lambda s:f"{s:05}".translate("bcdefghiAa"*9)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3dXISc5NSEhWKrdKUqoutDExrlfRKihLzinMSS1I1lJKSU1LT0jMyHROVtCw1oXrUC4oy80o00jRMjI0MjTV10jQszExMQbSxiRGIsgQCQ02o8gULIDQA)

Takes an integer and returns a string.

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript (ES6), 48 bytes

Expects an integer and returns a string.

```javascript
f=(n,k=5)=>k?f(n/10|0,k-1)+"Aabcdefghi"[n%10]:''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcnNDoIgAADge0/B3JowNUCwVRs1n6N1QH6UcNCyderdyc0u@V2/u3zLST3d41WFqE1KVsBQetEgcfYXCwOm5ENKX1FUZK3slDa2H1x2DVtKbqc8TyqGKY5mN8YeWshZTRlCAGOgVSfV5r/BYc@bpdvBarNuwHj961bpbtXHGV3azWT6Ag)

---

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 48 bytes

```c
k;f(n){k++>4?k=0:f(n/10)|putchar(n?n%10+96:65);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY7RDoIwDEXf@YqGxGTLIG4wiDCRDzE8LDPggk4DGElwv@6c0Jfb296eVMWdUs71okUGLz0hJ173FS293TOKP8/XpK5yQKY2O0ZJkZd5hoV1d6kNwrAEANpMcJGTPDdQwQI8TVgawSHnWQQpTyIofDGwIvDh9jGg/4H2WSq8HIF7IWRjbbTZL1eibsQ6bNGMt87/M6IwXJ0NrPuq9ia70cXvHw)

### 47 bytes

This version was suggested by [@jdt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41374/jdt).

```c
i;f(*o,x){for(i=5;i;x/=10)o[--i]=x?96+x%10:65;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3RCoIwGIXvfYofQdhylqaObEkPYl6IMBnYJmo0EF@9tUSpzs2Bc77//HVQt5VsjBGMo50iGk9c9UjkKRNMH/IoxKoIAlHm@ppRX3tReKYpm42QI9wrIRGGyQGrTyBk9xiHooQcJkjiYxQTONEkJRAnRwKZVQQzW3j7BtByZOmQWbtAYs33t8VtVVtgXRYl@6tUQX8SjhQBjb9B11uII9fbp@1wky4BtbazM5tXzduqGUzwfAM)

Comment: Impressive! Javascript is not mostly a good language for golfing but this is really awesome

Comment: [45 bytes](https://tio.run/##JY7RDoIwDEXf@YrGBLJlEBmMRZzGDzE8LDPDBZ0GMJLgft05oS/3tr09qcpapbzvhEYWz4R0MU@S4Lc0x5/na1RX2SN7sjHNSc33vMLC@bs0FmGYIwBjR7jIUZ4bOMIMrCxomcKOsyqFkhUp1KEoOBGFsH706H9gQjYXQQ7AghCyslbaFJYL0TRiGWo04dWFfwa02Sydi5z/Kn2T7eCz9w8)

Comment: @c-- This is very tempting and [I did a similar suggestion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252387/58563) some days ago. But, as I said for the other answer, the function will not be reusable anymore when `k` overflows.

Comment: Is `k=0` really needed? Yea you can only execute the function once, but isn't that enough?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 [Our consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4940/58563) is that functions have to be reusable arbitrarily often.

Comment: Trying [this](https://tio.run/##XcnNCoIwAADge08xhNiG1DY3pQKLPYd42K8uZIuMTr37EuyS3/W7q7eazTM8XoeYrMvZt7G9xq7pbxBePIqE0RJCXBZSaWOdH8ZQdHHP6If22aQ4p8kdpzQgjwSvGMcYEAKs0crs/hucGlGvLUdv3bYBF9WvpbF60@cFWzssVP4C) but floating issue

Answer (score 7):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>69</s> <s>67</s> <s>63</s> 61 bytes

```c
f(x,o,i)char*o;{for(memset(o,65,i=5);x;x/=10)o[--i]=x%10+96;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVDbboMwDH0uX2F1qpSM0EG5qChlP8J4QCnQSJBUhEqREL@@zEF9mF/sc2wfX0QkxlYN7kMqMb7uHdzMcpf6/PgO/lOzVANyrieWaSapeLTzp@Zrr2cydZPpFqJZkTNZ5ZRbbr@qJKa6jiLZVPaUxGFZ8M1JtcDUSkUorEFw8FCq52sxdQMVrJCllyRlcC2ynEGaXRiUaAlsHKtxFJC9BWtjju4GGbow9GqHXc1i6q0oG46k3xN0ne/ALw@a@vCJBy09OZ7OuflRxze9BcHmfkU/toNxET6iEtfyDw)

- thanks to [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat) for saving 4+2 bytes

Answer (score 6):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Takes input as a string.

```
c+48 ù'A5
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=Yys0OCD5J0E1&input=IjI0OCI)

```
c+48 ù'A5     :Implicit input of string
c+48          :Map charcodes, adding 48 to each
     ù'A5     :Left pad with "A" to length 5
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 50 bytes

```python
lambda l:''.join(chr(96+i)for i in l).rjust(5,'A')
```

Takes a list of integers as input

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHHSl1dLys/M08jOaNIw9JMO1MzLb9IIVMhM08hR1OvKKu0uETDVEfdUV3zf0FRZl6JRppGtImOsY6RjqGOcaymJhdc1ELHTMdExxRFzBgoYoQiYqkDgYZA0f8A)

Comment: Please could the downvoter explain why this was downvoted? It works fine for all test cases.

Answer (score 6):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org), 29 bytes

```
[ >dec 48 v+n 5 65 pad-head ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY5NqsJAEIT3c4rai4L5kRgh4OoReLgRV8HFOOkYcRzzZjrCQzyJm2z0Fh7E2xgde9NFVX9FX--VVHy03fO8WuaLnxR7soY0HP21ZBQ5OLY7s3U4SK5HjbSO7Ed740Rv3EEfldQOjSXm_6YnGDORL1Jw3dNi_pvPlymykhRMe9iQzXyvKDTxreVqmDwKn0cJTgODGJMYjSyHNckSa3_zDNIMlTgjCoNxiGQSxQijANN-xrigQIX-EY0R1iCpaiG-ZNf5_QI)

-6 from chunes.

Comment: `[ 48 + ] map` => `48 v+n` and you're allowed to take input as a string so you don't need `>dec`.

Answer (score 6):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 5 bytes (10 nibbles)

```
&"A"5+'`'
```

```
     +     # add each element of input
      '`'  # to '`' character
&          # then justify the text
 "A"       # using the "A" character
    5      # to a width of 5
```

[image]

Comment: Your code shows the first character as `&`, but your explanation shows a `$`. Is this a typo?

Comment: @TheThonnu Yes I wanted to say that too

Comment: Oh, yes, it's a typo.  Sorry!

Comment: (and if you're interested, the list of commands is [here](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/quickref.html))...

Answer (score 6):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$14\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 11.524 bytes

```
$t5$J*/A5OC+96
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyIkdDUkSiovQTVPQys5NiIsIls4LDYsNCw1XSJd)

Comment: No pad operator really hurts...

Answer (score 5):

## Excel (ms365), <s>63</s> 61 bytes

-2 Thanks to [@EngineerToast](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38183/engineer-toast) for 61 bytes:

```
=RIGHT(CONCAT("AAAA",CHAR(96+MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1))),5)
```

Or, the original answer for 63 bytes:

```
=CONCAT(MID("Aabcdefghi",MID(TEXT(A1,"00000"),ROW(1:5),1)+1,1))
```

[image]

---

Note that it can probably be done with less bytes if input is an array of numbers but thought I'd take a single integer as startpoint.

Comment: 61 bytes `=RIGHT(CONCAT("AAAA",CHAR(96+MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1))),5)`

Answer (score 5):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org), 48 bytes

```
~x=replace(lpad(x,5,'A'),('1':'9'.=>'a':'i')...)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700qzQnM3HBgqWlJWm6FjcN6ipsi1ILchKTUzVyChJTNCp0THXUHdU1dTTUDdWt1C3V9Wzt1BOBrEx1TT09PU2oPs3cxAKNOh2FaBNjI0NjHQULMxNTHQVjEyMdBUsgMIzVVKixUyjOyC-HaIBZCAA)

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>67</s> 65 bytes

```julia
~x=getindex.([Dict(0:9 .=>['A';'a':'i'])],[0;0;0;0;x][end-4:end])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v67CNj21JDMvJbVCTyPaJTO5RMPAylJBz9YuWt1R3Vo9Ud1KPVM9VjNWJ9rAGgIrYqNT81J0TayAZKzm/7poEx1jHSMdQx3jWIUaO4WCosy8kpw8rrpoCx0zHRMd01gFBVRxY6CoEUgUTdxSBwINkc35DwA)

-2 bytes thanks to @MarcMush: replace `[[0,0,0,0];x]` with `[0;0;0;0;x]`

- Function is defined with the unary operater `~`
- The dictionary is wrapped in an array to allow [passing multiple values](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-can-i-access-multiple-values-of-a-dictionary-using-a-tuple-of-keys/56868?u=ashlin_harris).
- For padding, I concatenate a zero array and the input array. Only the last five elements `[end-4:end]` are used.

Comment: -2 bytes : `[0;0;0;0;x] `

Answer (score 5):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 42 bytes

```
y/123456789/abcdefghi/
:a
s/^.{,4}$/A&/
ta
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ODVlWbSSrqtS7IKlpSVpuhY3tSr1DY2MTUzNzC0s9ROTklNS09IzMvW5rBK5ivXj9Kp1TGpV9B3V9LlKEiE6oBoXbDExNjI05rIwMzHlMjYx4rIEAkOIHAA)

Answer (score 4):

## POSIX Shell Command Language + Utilities, 26 bytes

```sh
printf %05d $1|tr 0-9 Aa-i
```

Self-explanatory: printf renders the argument padded to five columns with zeroes, then tr does the transformation per spec.

Transcript of test cases:

```sh
$ cat a.sh; echo; wc -c a.sh
printf %05d $1|tr 0-9 Aa-i
26 a.sh
$ ./a.sh 8645; echo
Ahfde
$ ./a.sh 43213; echo
dcbac
$ ./a.sh 8645; echo
Ahfde
$ ./a.sh 342; echo
AAcdb
$ ./a.sh 99991; echo
iiiia
```

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 13 bytes

Full program prompting for digit number list

```apl
'A'@=¯5↑⎕⊇⌊⎕A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKO94L@6o7qD7aH1po/aJj7qm/qoq/1RTxeQ4QiS/a8ABgVcJgrGCkYKhgrGXDARCwUzBRMFUzjfGMgzgvMsFSDQEAA)

`⎕A` uppercase **A**lphabet

`⌊` Lowercase that

`⎕⊇` use the input to select from that (1-indexed)

`¯5↑` take the last 5 elements of that, adding padding elements on the left

`'A'` put "A"s where equal to the padding element

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
øA∑\A5ø↳
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiw7hB4oiRXFxBNcO44oazIiwiIiwiWzQsIDMsIDIsIDEsIDNdXG5bOCwgNiwgNCwgNV1cblszLCA0LCAyXVxuWzksIDksIDksIDksIDFdXG5bMSwgMl0iXQ==)

Finally, a use for some of the more niche string digraphs. Takes input as a list of digits, outputs a single string.

### Explained

```
øA∑\A5ø↳
øA        # Get the nth letter of the alphabet for each digit in the input
  ∑       # Join as a single string
   \A     # Push the string "A" to the stack
     5    # Push the number 5 to the stack
      ø↳  # And left pad the single string from early with "A"s until it's 5 characters long
```

Comment: Nooooo I was actually close to finding the answer till I saw this... dammit :(. Oh well, +1

Answer (score 3):

## [Thon](https://github.com/nayakrujul/thon), 19 bytes

```
n"Aabcdefghi"b5"A"J
```

Input as a number (e.g. `824`). Output as a string (e.g. `AAhbd`).

**Explanation**

```
n"Aabcdefghi"b5"A"J
n                    // Input a number
 "Aabcdefghi"        // Push the string of letters
             b       // Convert the number to Base-"Aabcdefghi" (see below)
              5"A"J  // Fill with "A" up to 5 characters
                     // (implicit output)
```

Converting to base-`"Aabcdefghi"` is a trick to replace every `"1"` with `"a"`, every `"2"` with `"b"`, etc.

## [Thon (Symbols)](https://github.com/nayakrujul/thon-symbols), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/nayakrujul/thon-symbols/blob/main/Codepage.md)

(Note: this language is newer than the challenge)

```
)ş{í1-å`;}""]5AṚ
```

**Explanation**

```
)ş{í1-å`;}""]5AṚ
)                 // Create an empty list
 ş                // Get input as a string
  {      }        // For each character in the input:
   í              //   Convert to an integer
    1-            //   Subtract 1
      å`          //   Push the lowercase alphabet and get the character
        ;         //   Append to the list
          ""]     // Join the list by an empty string
             5AṚ  // Fill the string with "A" up to 5 characters
                  // (implicit output)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
₃+>çΔ'Aš5.£
```

Input as a list of digits; output as a list of characters.
(If the inputs would have been 0-based (digits `0-9` mapping to `a-j`) instead of 1-based, the `>` could have been dropped.)

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UVOztt3h5eemqDseXWiqd2jx///RFjpmOiY6prEA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/R03N2naHl5@bou54dKGp3qHF/2t1/kdHG@kY6hjpGOsYx@pEmwBpEB/EttAx0zHRMQWyjIG0EZC21IFAw9hYAA).

Or alternatively:

```
5j9LðšA¬uì‡
```

Both input and output as a string.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fNMvS5/CGowsdD60pPbzmUcPC//8tzExMAQ) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/0yxLn8Mbji50PLSm9PCaRw0L/@v8j1YyMjQyNlbSUTIxNjIE0RZmJqZAytjECEhaAoGhUiwA).

**Explanation:**

Unfortunately 05AB1E lacks a left-pad up to length builtin (unless by spaces), so most of the bytes are to account for that in the first program..

```python
₃+>          # Add 96 to each value
   ç         # Convert each from a codepoint-integer to a character
    Δ        # Loop until the result no longer changes:
     'Aš    '#  Prepend an "A"
        5.£  #  Leave (up to) the last 5 characters from the list
             # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

```python
5j           # Left-pad the (implicit) input-string with spaces up to length 5
  9L         # Push list [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    ðš       # Prepend a space: [" ",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  A          # Push the lowercase alphabet: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
   ¬         # Push its first character (without popping): "a"
    u        # Uppercase it: "A"
     ì       # Prepend it: "Aabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
      ‡      # Transliterate the space-padded input from [" ",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] to
             # "Aabcdefghij..."
             # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [simply 0.11](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/simply/), 66 bytes

This abuses bugs in the parser, to save bytes.
It works with the commit [98783927a8a232b8e0afb46f380e02348b0f7cbb](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/simply/tree/98783927a8a232b8e0afb46f380e02348b0f7cbb) - current commit at the time.
The behaviour will, VERY LIKELY, change in the future.

Creates an anonymous function that receives an array of numbers, and outputs the value.

```
fn($L){if$l=&len($L)<5for$_ in$l..4out'A'each$L as$i;out!ABCL[$i]}
```

### Example of usage:

This should output `"AAfcf"`.

```
$fn = fn($L){if$l=&len($L)<5for$_ in$l..4out'A'each$L as$i;out!ABCL[$i]}
call $fn([5,2,5]);
```

### How it works?

It simply checks the length of the array, and if it is lower than 5, it outputs 1 to 5 `'A'`s.

It goes from 0 to 4 because it uses a range operator.
Going from 4 to 4, is just 1 iteration - the number 4 itself.
Going from 0 to 4, is 5 iterations - the number 0, number 1, number 2, number 3 and number 4.

Then, it uses the pre-existing constant `!ABCL`, which contains the letters from `a` to `z`, in lowercase.
The values in the array are used as indexes into the constant.

### Ungolfed

Very code-y looking:

```
$fn = fn($list) => {
    $len = &len($list);
    if $len < 5 then {
        for $_ in $len..4 {
            echo 'A';
        }
    }
    
    foreach $list as $index {
        echo !ABCL[$index];
    }
};
```

Pseudo-code looking:

```
Set $fn to an anonymous function($list)
Begin.
    Set $len to the result of calling &len($list).
    In case $len < 5 then
    Begin.
        Loop from $len to 4 as $_
        Begin.
            Show the value 'A'.
        End.
    End.
    
    Loop through $list as $index
    Begin.
        Show the contents of !ABCL[$index].
    End.
End.
```

All versions do the exact same.

Answer (score 3):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
(h5,'A*\É▄\§
```

Input as a list of digits; output as string.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/18jw1RH3VEr5nDno2ktMYeW//8fbaRjqGMEhMaxXNEmOsY6ID6IbaFjpmOiYwpkGQNpIyBtqQOBhrEA)

Or alternatively:

```
▄▒\(§y♫α'A═╡
```

Input as a list of digits; output as a string wrapped inside a list.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///RtJZH0ybFaBxaXvlo5upzG9UdH02d8Gjqwv//o410DHWMgNA4livaRMdYB8QHsS10zHRMdEyBLGMgbQSkLXUg0DAWAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
(        # Decrease each digit in the (implicit) input-list by 1
         # (because MathGolf uses 0-based indexing)
 h       # Push the length of the list (without popping)
  5,     # Calculate 5-length
    'A* '# Repeat "A" that many times
 \       # Swap so the list as at the top again
  É      # For-each over the digits, using 3 characters as inner code-block:
   ▄     #  Push the lowercase alphabet
    \    #  Swap so the current digit is at the top
     §   #  Index the digit into the alphabet
         # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly as result)
```

```python
▄        # Push the lowercase alphabet
 ▒       # Convert it to a list of characters
  \      # Swap so the (implicit) input-list is at the top
   (     # Decrease each digit by 1 (because MathGolf uses 0-based indexing)
    §    # Index each digit in the list into the alphabet list
     y   # Join it back together again
♫        # Push 10000
 α       # Pair it with the earlier string
  'A═   '# Pad both to an equal length by left-padding with "A"
     ╡   # Remove the last item from the pair (the 10000)
         # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 21 bytes

```
T`d`_l
^
AAAA
!`.{5}$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wPyQhJSE@hyuOyxEIuBQT9KpNa1X@/zcxNjI05rIwMzHlMjYx4rIEAkMA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
T`d`_l
```

Translate digits to lowercase letters.

```
^
AAAA
```

Prefix four `A`s.

```
!`.{5}$
```

Take the last 5 letters.

A port of @Jiří's sed answer is also 21 bytes:

```
T`d`_l
+`^.{0,4}$
A$&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wPyQhJSE@h0s7IU6v2kDHpFaFy1FF7f9/E2MjQ2MuCzMTUy5jEyMuSyAwBAA) Link includes test cases.

Answer (score 3):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), <s>17</s> 15 bytes

*Edit: -2 bytes thanks to Razetime*

```
¯5↑"AAAA"∾+⟜'`'
```

[Try it at BQN REPL](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=QWFhYSDihpAgwq814oaRIkFBQUEi4oi+K+KfnCdgJwpBYWFhIDHigL8y4oC/Mw==)

```
          +⟜'`'     # add each element of input to the '`' character
         ∾          # join this to 
   "AAAA"           # "AAAA" (shorter than (5⥊'A'))
_5↑                 # take -5 elements
                    # (which takes 5 elements from the end)
```

Comment: `¯5↑` takes from the end

Comment: @Razetime - Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 64 bytes

```
>>>>>+>,[>,]<<<<<<-[---[----<+>]<++.>>-]>[<-[----->+<]>---.[-]>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v/fDgS07XSi7XRibcBAN1pXF4x1bbTtYm20tfXs7HRj7aIhErq6dto2sXZAWi8aKBr7/7@JobkpAA)

### Explanation

```
>>>>>+>
```

Move to position 5, make the value there 1, and move to position 6.

```
,[>,]
```

Read the digits into consecutive positions from there onward.

```
<<<<<<
```

Move 6 positions to the left. From here, each 0 before the 1 in position 5 indicates an `A` to be output.

```
-[---[----<+>]<++.>>-]
```

Subtract 1. Loop while it's not 0 (thus was not 1):

- Subtract 3 more, making −4.
- Loop subtracting 4 and adding 1 to the left, producing (256-4)/4=63 in the cell to the left.
- Move left, add 2 more for 65, and output that (`A`).
- Move right twice, for a net movement of 1 to the right, and subtract 1 (and repeat).

```
>[<-[----->+<]>---.[-]>]
```

Move right. Loop while it's not 0 (over all the digits):

- Move left and subtract 1, making −1.
- Loop subtracting 5 and adding 1 to the right, adding (256-1)/5=51 to the digit's character code.
- Move right and subtract 3, for a net +48 to the digit's character code. 48 is the difference between `1` and `a`, and likewise for the other digits (as both digits and letters are contiguous in ASCII).
- Output the letter produced from the digit.
- Zero that position (as it will be reused in the next iteration) and move right (and repeat).

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 38 bytes

```
\(d)intToUtf8(tail(c(!1:5,d+31),5)+65)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY31WI0UjQz80pC8kNL0iw0ShIzczSSNRQNrUx1UrSNDTV1TDW1zUw1oaot04CSJjrGOkY6hjrGmppcIL6FjpmOCVAdhGcMZBtB2ZY6EGioCTVgwQIIDQA)

Takes input as a vector of digits, outputs a string.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3.8/),  <s>42</s>  41 bytes

-1 thanks to [loopy walt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/107561/loopy-walt)'s suggestion to use XOR, `^`, instead of addition.

```python
lambda a:[chr(96^d)for d in[33]*5+a][-5:]
```

An unnamed function that accepts a list of integers from \$[1,9]\$ and returns a list of characters.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzBDoIwGIPvPkVvbPp7gAkBEnyROZPpXCBRWOYuhvDsc/Ng08PXNqn7hHGZRet8tMMlPvXrZjR0L@@jZ11zNdwuHgbTLIVQ@/qglTzWvYq5Do93SAuYPBEEoSKUCRRBtoSGkOo6J/HDKmNH@LtUvN8hyflpDswWlq35c@MYzlgty4FvBY9f)**

Comment: `lambda a:[chr(96^d)for d in[33]*5+a][-5:]` saves a byte.

Comment: Nice save @loopywalt, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 9 bytes

```
.[\A5m@Gt
```

[Test suite](https://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=.%5B%5CA5m%40Gt&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B4%2C3%2C2%2C1%2C3%5D%0A%5B8%2C6%2C4%2C5%5D%0A%5B3%2C4%2C2%5D%0A%5B9%2C9%2C9%2C9%2C1%5D&debug=0)

This answer uses a sufficiently different approach from the existing Pyth answer(s).

###### Explanation:

```
.[\A5m@Gt   | Full code
.[\A5m@GtdQ | with implicit variables
------------+----------------------------------------------------
     m    Q | Replace each number d in the input with
      @G    |  the character of the lowercase alphabet with index
        td  |  d minus 1
.[\A5       | Pad the array on the left with A to a length of 5
```

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 13 bytes

```
"A"^-5$`c$96+
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k/#eJxNj81qwzAQhO96ikX40FIU4d/YEhR87KkPEFIsyfIPSeTWlqlNaZ+9slxCZ077McvONgyX+I2kQaWCIntCyLKv4LT+jKwBgIVXw4U/VI3or3zhKx8fz9/InkL4M8diEz47GDkQOcccSyGl8tAhjsuyFNKPCcSw5VymVlLsmRwySCB1ua6ptUexA35R1ftiAbvdxd5pu4go6qx9nxilaqh1O1ybw2SFuuhFdcK0+qCGG/2Y9WT7wUw0SqNjmlMz36QeiR3IZMfetKQ3xD9BPsWK0IthkMRRGAN5htfZMvBFPc+zJIU79209j5MI/vGttOeFU3jnvvcvN7RnGg==)

- `` `c$96+ `` convert input of digits to corresponding letters
- `-5$` left-pad to length 5 with spaces
- `"A"^` fill spaces with "A" (and implicitly return)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 37 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to [Dingus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92901/dingus)

```ruby
->a{a.map{''<<_1+96}.join.rjust 5,?A}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGiNNulpSVpuhY3VXXtEqsT9XITC6rV1W1s4g21Lc1q9bLyM_P0irJKi0sUTHXsHWuhij0LSkuKFdKio010jHWMdAx1jGNjuWBiFjpmOiY6pkgixkC-ERLfUgcCDWNjIQYuWAChAQ)

Comment: [37 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGiNNulpSVpuhY3VXXtEqsT9XITC6rV1W1s4g21Lc1q9bLyM_P0irJKi0sUTHXsHWuhij0LSkuKFdKio010jHWMdAx1jGNjuWBiFjpmOiY6pkgixkC-ERLfUgcCDWNjIQYuWAChAQ), [alternative 37 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGiNNulpSVpuhY3VXXtEqs17B21TLQT9XITC6rV1W1s4g21Lc1qtdTVNaN1TXVMY2uhij0LSkuKFdKio010jHWMdAx1jGNjuWBiFjpmOiZAxQgRYyDfCIlvqQOBhrGxEAMXLIDQAA).

Comment: @Dingus Nice work!

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 18 bytes

```
V-5lzp"A")Vzp@GtsN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P0zXNKeqQMlRSTOsqsDBvaTY7/9/YxMjAA)

#### Explanation

```
V-5lzp"A")Vzp@GtsN
V                   # For loop with N as variable
    z               # Input
   l                # Length
 -5lz               # Subtract length of input from 5
     p"A"           # Prints "A"
         )          # End of for loop
            p       # Print without any additional newline
              G     # Initialized to "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                sN  # Cast N to an integer
               t    # Subtract 1
             @      # Get element at index
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 13 bytes

```
✂⁺×⁴A⭆Ｓ§β⊖ι±⁵
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYpBCoMwFAWvElw9Id1pKXQldOOiItgLpPFhAzGV@C29/W@gsxtm/Mtl/3ZRdcwhCaYYPDHGY8cjrNzRWFN1VW3NJGVY7m5Dn7ZD/ooSOunTzC@e1tzoM1cm4YxQF6wZuDgh2iJX1cu5afX0iT8) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
    A           Literal string `A`
  ×             Repeated
   ⁴            Literal integer `4`
 ⁺              Concatenated to
      Ｓ         Input as a string
     ⭆          Map over digits
        β       Predefined variable lowercase alphabet
       §        Indexed by
          ι     Current digit
         ⊖      Decremented
✂               Sliced from
            ⁵   Literal integer `5`
           ±    Negated
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 39 bytes

```powershell
-join($args|%{[char](96+$_)})|% *ft 5 A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkqZgq1D9XzcrPzNPQyWxKL24RrU6OjkjsShWw9JMWyVes1azRlVBK61EwVTB8X8tl5oCUIuJgrGCkYKhgjGEa6FgBhQyhXCMgUwjCNMSCg3/AwA)

Takes integers as unnamed arguments.
Nothing fancy, just adds 96 to get to the ASCII code of 'a', casts to a char, joins the chars to a string, then pipes the string to % (an alias for ForEach-Object), which will call the string's member "PadLeft". Output is implicit.

Answer (score 2):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 34 bytes

I think I’m finally starting to get the hang of J-uby. A few bytes shorter than [my Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252777/11261).

```
:*&(:+&96|:chr)|:join|~:rjust&?A&5
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWN5WstNQ0rLTVLM1qrJIzijRrrLLyM_Nq6qyKskqLS9TsHdVMoSo9C0pLihXcoqNNdIx1jHQMdYxjY7lgYhY6ZjomOqZIIsZAvhES31IHAg1jYyEGLlgAoQE)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-plF`, 24 bytes

```perl
$_=A x(5-@F).y/1-9/a-i/r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3tZRoULDVNfBTVOvUt9Q11I/UTdTv@j/fxNjI0NjLgszE1MuYxMjLksgMPyXX1CSmZ9X/F/X11TPwNDgv25BjhsA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>14</s> <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
@L+\AG+mZ-5l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/38FHO8bRXTs3Stc05///aAsdMx0THdNYAA)

**Explanation:**

```
@L+\AG+mZ-5l # whole program

             # implicit output
 L           # left map with lambda d:
@            # using index
  +          #  concatenate
   \A        #   literal "A"
     G       #   and literal "abc...xyz"
      +      # into a concatenation of:
       mZ    #  a constructed list of n zeroes
             #   where n is: (the 2nd argument for m is supplied an int)
         -5  #    the difference of 5
           l #    and the length of implicit input (Q)
             #  and the implicit input (Q)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 62 bytes

```
func[s][forall s[s/1: #"`"+ s/1]pad/left/with rejoin s 5 #"A"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYtBCoMwFET3OcWQLruQGC2tu16h28@HBk3QIlGSlB4//aAzmzfDTPJTffmJWIWhhm8cKTOFLbl1RabcmAEX/dZXCPLupmb1oTS/pcxI/rMtERm9TJ6aq9y8G2dpSEFEHSxaGFg@8h03dOjPZIXbkx84bFgx7WmJBQGZ6x8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 50 bytes

```red
func[v][insert/dup v 17 5 take/last/part v + 48 5]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9BDoMgAATvvmLrtWkUBavtL3olHIhiNLVoEK2/t6ilSTccyM4kLEZV60NVXKC@rfWkSz4L3upRGRtV04AZ5AoGK58q6uRoo0Ea69ozaA4m1ro3SpYNWj1MFjyAC2cJGAGLQQt3EVt3R0jThKTh18jAKDYv3fFh5BllXiA7jT09hJQmnrtV/tDCP1G4kDAQxw6/bUGNl/sAZlXa3pz@xm4ZTKth@0vZSINlr0XwA1q9u1arQKwf)

Takes input as a vector of code points and returns output as the same.

- `insert/dup v 17 5` Insert five 17s at the beginning
- `v + 48` Add 48 to each element
- `take/last/part v 5` Take the last five elements

Comment: Nice! Good choice of input and output types.

Comment: @GalenIvanov Thanks! Means a lot coming from our local Red guru.

Comment: I'm far from being a guru :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 31 bytes

```
{TR/0..9/Aa..i/}o*.fmt('%05d')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcHdCkAwGAbgW3mT/4Nv2CbLT7kFOZdipYjGieTax/Mcs1lzu93wNWr79B1LiBRrR6KFvXtMervCwEvkFES2xDnecNwBdYNHwx1eB3o3qATPUo4iFxJcZFC/tLEf)

`*.fmt('%05d')` is an anonymous function that formats its integer argument to five digits, padded on the left with zeroes.  `{ TR/0..9/Aa..i/ }` is a second anonymous function that transliterates its string argument, turning 0 into A and 1-9 into a-i.  The `o` operator composes those two functions.

Answer (score 2):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 67 bytes

```rust
|a|format!("{:A>5}",a.map(|d|char::from(d+96)).collect::<String>())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc4/b8IwEAXwnU9xyVDZ6jUSBBBcaaSMzB2rChn/KZYSp3WOLoTPnrpljMq7@XfvxXPPowvQKh@EhMsMUhrL4AhcED0bom@rifaBuz3buDtvKglPFbxy9OEDXmAc1OC62CrORH6hulpdc1RFqz7FYAZ9UpHIxa4V5nG7lrLQXdNYzUS724tKSDk@/xWrvreRD/YrEw9OpN7sbYklLnCO5Xvh04SDTxsSQMiNPiqdy3/lBte4xNXE1Sdn7B1XJrWYqlqb4x21xdvNJ9KnqF95nY0/)

Answer (score 2):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>142</s> <s>138</s> 137 bytes

-4 thanks to [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat).

First time golfing in C++, there are probably many places where improvements could be made. `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` was really expensive in terms of bytes.

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
int f(int n){for(int i=5;i--;){putchar(((n%(int)exp10(i+1))/(int)exp10(i))?(n%(int)exp10(i+1))/exp10(i)+96:65);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY7NCoMwEITP5ikCpZBFrKb@UI1tn8VGrQEbQ4xQEJ89NUKhh4J7GHZmPtjlSgVPzq09CMn7qW7KhzBjOJqa@/6puyEhDW6JUwlzO@htFdeUiSBgMKvJ8K7ShBB5dBU0b0UjInwKEP4GAPd/yLf186zIUmDLYt2BVyUkgRl5LUniM42BIW/9qSj4MBlclngzjax75phLlqQ7SJycd4h8HeoY3ZhJSxwxtNgP)

Takes integer inputs and outputs as string.

Comment: [102 bytes](https://tio.run/##hY1dCoMwAIOf11MUxqCdOv9lWt3O4qrOSq2lVhiIZ@@sFzAPIYEvhErpfSk15spGOSldfpie/Vk31HEe/QswoWGHrAu8dpM6IqtSd3A5YZ5H5KJpXyskboPP34c7eVZkKca8an8yDBDD7lCFwZ2Tzdj5WDOB8AouHUriKIwxAZf9sSjotGhYlvAorWg4scwzS9ITJE6iEyLfFVpGtXpRAgYEbOYP "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: [58 bytes](https://tio.run/##lYxLCoMwAET3OUWgtChV6h812h5EXIT4aUCjJJEGxKs3NfYEzmbgMW/IPLs9IRovcoJdqavaokxC5RhwE/baTfwgtIwRRepR@p4tKteldale6up79yzJkxhtGgFwoYwMS9PCgk5C8haPTwDIG3MolaxSr9435mzElFn2CuCezorCwA8dM7HRgYRs8pxMi4RFYbCpg7WsGfaLv5YmUXzeCqPgvJTt8c9qvJULZ9BDYAP6S7oB90K7nx8) as a lambda

Comment: [53 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY7dioMwEIWvm6cYKAumKo31h9bo7oOIFxKTbsTGYiIrW3z1dU3suZhhPg5nDns@wztj63psuZCKg/DmQGMxjJ5UBroypR2dz2VEsK7CsKvL@Wv@iIh/y/IsXY9SsX5qORRy0GbkzeMTIfbdjGBmU11JTRGyOY9GKg/DC8EmCwzXRlc1lPCCJL5EcQDXLEkDiJNLALdNESzU2bcu4MrIklCQhZa/fBCeS8Bwhvd92sHm8H376fC2VLIObBu8px20afOcDZOBorDcLse4avvds7g5cjONCghFy/rHRN/c9Rr@/AM) as a preprocessor macro.

Answer (score 2):

## [C#](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 43 bytes

```cs
x=>x.PadLeft(5,'').Select(y=>(char)(y+48))
```

`` represents the character with code `17`; `48` is added to this to produce `A`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY9BS8QwEIXPzc1/MPSyCdYcdAWh214WFWWFhT3sQTzE2WkNpAlmUtki@9trix5E8DhvHu99D/kCGceerW9hN3CirhS/L72x/v2PtA7OESYbPP//0ffkKVosBTrDDNsY2mg6@BQZJ5MswkewB3gy1ktOcQp5fgETW1az5a73uPqWC3i49X1H0bw6WuGbiXUNDVQwHqv6qLfmsKEmyeticbZQekczgByqWs5WJYfz5Y1SY1auJ6jgSO@jTTStop9a/RgmhDwvGplfLS9zpVQpspM4jV8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), 41 bytes

```
&for<<x<-String.rjust(&1,5,17)>>,do: x+48
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83JrMgs@p9m@18tLb/IxqbCRje4pCgzL12vKKu0uERDzVDHVMfQXNPOTicl30qhQtvE4r@nv15BaUmxQpqehpKJsZGhsZKmgrKCf2mJlUJKclJiMheyAgszE1OgPEyBY0ZaSiqKAmMTI5A8XIFjckoSigJLIDBEWJEJBIn/AQ)

Comment: This is cool. I honestly don't recall seeing an Elixir answer here before.

Answer (score 2):

## x86-16 machine code, <del>20</del> 17 bytes

```
00000000: fcb8 4141 abab fd03 f14e ac04 30aa e2fa  ..AA.....N..0...
00000010: c3
```

Callable function, custom calling convention. Input string at `DS:[SI]`, `CX` = input string length (1-5), output string buffer at `ES:[DI]`.

Listing:

```
FC          CLD                 ; string direction forward
B8 4141     MOV AX, 'AA'        ; AL and AH = pad char
AB          STOSW               ; pad only first 4 chars
AB          STOSW 
FD          STD                 ; string direction reverse
03 F1       ADD  SI, CX         ; SI = end of input string
4E          DEC  SI             ; SI = last char of input
    A_LOOP:
AC          LODSB               ; load next char
04 30       ADD  AL, 'a'-'1'    ; aaaaaa convert
AA          STOSB               ; write to output
E2 FA       LOOP A_LOOP
C3          RET                 ; return to caller
```

##### Test program output:

[image]

**Props:**
-3 bytes thx to @l4m2!

Comment: Your second call fails due to wrong direction

Comment: @l4m2 oh, do you mean because there's no explicit `CLD` in the beginning? Okay... that's fair - as a DOS standalone I can assume `DF=0`, but as a function I cannot. Will fix.

Comment: `push cx/.../pop cx` => `mov ax, 'AA'/stosw/stosw`

Comment: @l4m2 wow, that seems so obvious now that you mention that! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
r5l6=.a7+!
68*+o
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/vyjH1Na@LNFcW5HLzEJLO9/u////usXGJkYA)

**Explanation**

```
r        !    # reverse stack on first iteration
 5l6=.        # if stack length is 5, move to next row
      a7+     # else add 17 to stack
68*+o         # add 48 to each item on stack and print as char
```

Answer (score 2):

## k, 18 bytes

```
"A"^-5$10h$96+10\:
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), <s>11</s> <s>10</s> 9 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
⬚@A↙¯5+@`
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAg4qyaQEHihpnCrzUrQGAKCmYgWzQgMyAyIDEgM10KZiBbOCA2IDQgNV0KZiBbMyA0IDJdCmYgWzkgOSA5IDkgMV0=)

- -1 byte from Dominic van Essen
- -1 byte from Bubbler

```
 ⬚@A↙¯5+@`
       +@`  # add backtick character
 ⬚@A↙¯5     # take the last five characters, filling any excess with A
```

Comment: [10 bytes](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAg4oeM4qyaQEHihpk14oeMK0BgCgpmIFsxIDIgM10KZiBbOV0KZiBbOSA5IDkgOSAxXQ==): ```⇌⬚@A↙5⇌+@` ```

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Ah, of course. Thanks!

Comment: 9 bytes: ``⬚@A↙¯5+@` ``

Comment: @Bubbler Excellent. I had no idea negative-take was a thing.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 25 bytes

```
iry5L[f5f-['Ao,]]pp['0+o]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z@zqNLUJzrNNE03Wt0xXyc2tqAgWt1AOz/2/38TAA)

Pretty straight forward reading of the rules...

```
ir                        - read the digits in a codepoints, reverse stack
  y5                      - push digit count, push "5"
    L                     - check: digitCount<5
     [          ]pp       - exec block if digit count < 5
      f5f-                - subtract digit count from 5, get pad count
          [   ,]          - loop once for each pad digit...
           'Ao            - print "A"
                   [    ] - loop or all the codepoints on the stack
                    '0+   - convert from 0-9 to a-i
                       o  - print as character
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
DịØa;@”Ax5¤Uḣ5U
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/l4e7uwzMSrR0eNcx1rDA9tCT04Y7FpqH/D7c/aloT@f9/tImxkaGxjoKFmYmpjoKxiZGOgiUQGMYCAA)

Almost certainly I'm missing some atoms or syntax tricks that can get this down further. 11 bytes are spent to handle the padding.

Explanation:

```
DịØa;@”Ax5¤Uḣ5U
D               get decimal representation
 ịØa            index into lowercase alphabet
      ”Ax5¤     repeat "A" 5 times
    ;@          prepend "A"s to the other string
           Uḣ5U take the last 5 characters
```

Comment: -2 bytes: `DịØa”Ax5¤;ṫ-4`. There's got to be a builtin but I can't find it either.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 29 bytes

There probably is a shorter way (perhaps with `a.`) than a hard-coded string mapping, but everything I tried ended up being longer.

```
'Aabcdefghi'{~],~[:0"0[:i.5-#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P83WSt0xMSk5JTUtPSNTvbouVqcu2spAySDaKlPPVFf5f2pyRr5CmoKJjrGOkY6hjjEXVMBCx0zHRMcUxjUGcoxgHEsdCDT8DwA)

Takes input as array of numbers and outputs a string.

Answer (score 1):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang) (v2), 41 bytes

```
;=iP;=s*'A'5;Wi;=s+sA+96[i=i]iO Gs-Ls 5 5
```

[Try it online!](https://knight-lang.netlify.app/#WyI7PWlQOz1zKidBJzU7V2k7PXMrc0ErOTZbaT1pXWlPIEdzLUxzIDUgNSIsIjg2NDUiLCIyLjAiXQ==)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-nl`, 28 bytes

```ruby
p$_.rjust(5).tr" 1-9","Aa-i"
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcnm0km5ejlLsgqWlJWm6FnsKVOL1irJKi0s0TDX1SoqUFAx1LZV0lBwTdTOVIEqgKhdsMTE2MjTmsjAzMeUyNjHisgQCQ4gcAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), <s>62</s> 45 bytes

```arturo
$[s][pad.with:`A`join map s=>[to :char 96+]5]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?4gHwU1)

Answer (score 1):

ultra verbose `awk` solution:

```
echo '43213
8645
342
99991' |
```

> ```
> awk '$!NF=sprintf("%c%c%c%c%c",___+(__+$(_=($(_<_)=sprintf("%.*d%s",5-NF,
>          _=_<_,$_))^_))^!!$_,___+(__+$++_)^!!$_,(__+$++_)^!!$_+___,
>         ___+(__+$++_)^!!$_,___+(__+$++_)^!!$_)' __=32 ___=64 FS=
> ```

```
dcbac
Ahfde
AAcdb
iiiia
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ÄLJ'A5ṙ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDMyU4NExKJ0E1JUUxJUI5JTk5JmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9MyUyQzQlMkMyJmZsYWdzPQ==)

##### Explanation

```python
ÄLJ'A5ṙ  '# Implicit input
Ä         # Number to alphabet
 L        # Lowercase each
  J       # Join into a string
   'A    '# Using "A" as a filler,
     5ṙ   # pad the string to length 5
          # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 110 bytes

Takes the number and returns the converted string in the aaaaa way.

```rust
|x:u64|"A".repeat((4-x.ilog(10))as _)+&x.to_string().bytes().fold(format!(""),|mut s,b|{s.push((48+b)as _);s})
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=vZLBToNAEIbjlaeYcmh2LQXb0gbBmvgMJnpoGrK0u5UEFsIuCAJP4qUHfSQP-jQupUlj7NG4l91k_vm_-TP7-pblQu6_Lh4Zh5iEHGGotYhKYLAE61JrSjdf2I1-p5sZTSmRyB6XZhglOzS5wkRALsIXikfD0pSJL2QW8h3CZlBJKtTNkmiLWJLFRA6QrmOjiXMJwgiaWphpLp4Qsp1R0Bn52BMtPgP8QeyVf46ru8idtlgWdDNYLebeb-zaK0xaSsq36Dw-JilqguaAwF7RapfWey7Z2Pnk_xvrSP3wtMMulYvcEEGFCys1hQf2Wm13Zc-mk5kBzsKeGzCzpwZcqzNZe5piQQkhP3WqXwEAltXZZeTZhQe6ucmdW-XDUIm9U7UgUU5duD-EUOX-4bosS2JfzeX4USJEhYbKBpshlwnq21OlkxFXCRmqyxar3rpqdQOqI0TJWk1r-3D7fX9_Aw)

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 93 bytes

Returns a byte slice, i.e. `Vec<u8>` instead that corresponds to the ASCII-encoded aaaaa string.

```rust
|x:u64|{let mut v=vec![65;(4-x.ilog(10))as _];v.extend(x.to_string().bytes().map(|b|48+b));v}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=tZJNTsMwEIXFNqeYZlHZbRpom1YhpkicAQkWVRQ5rV0i5U-xE1KSnIRNF3AhdnAanKQIIboEb8bSvHnfjMfPL1ku5OHj7J7HENEgRhgqLWQSOKzgfKTVpZMvrVq_0c2MpYxKZE1KMwiTHZpeYCogF8ETw-NhacrEEzIL4h3Cpr-XTKjIk3CLeJJFVA6QrmOjjnIJwvDrSphpLh4Qsuyx3xp5mIgGnwD-IPbKP8dV7cittlgVbDNYLxfkN9YlhclKyeItOo2PaIpqv-4QmBSNNjp_zSWf2O_uv3KOkDeidatTIrmhggkH1gpKwHLVMtfWfDadG2AvrYUBc2tmwKU6U5do6sWghCD-rlSfAABas4w-OnDHNle5fa1cOCox-coVNMyZA7ddfyrZXxyHZ0nkqZ5sL0yE2KOhMsFmEMsE9cWp0skwVjviqCobrGqrfaMbsFe3zlXpGk07TnY49PET)